# why curl can't expand variable inside the loop, but echo can?

Tags: variable, curl, variable-substitution

I need to include variable inside curl

```
for fname in "assets/*.drx"; do
    echo $fname
    curl -F file=@"$fname" "http://someurl.com/"    
    echo $fnamename
done
```

Result:

```
assets/5baa5caa414f1d7786e86d03_1545903119.11.drx
curl: (26) couldn't open file "assets/*.drx"
assets/5baa5caa414f1d7786e86d03_1545903119.11.drx
```

It seems curl uses glob expression, but echo uses actual filename. Why does curl behave like this? Why does echo see the actual variable and how can I use the filename inside curl?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've quoted the `*` wildcard, preventing the shell from expanding it.

```
for fname in assets/*.drx; do
    printf '%s\n' "$fname"
    curl -F file=@"$fname" "http://someurl.com/"    
done
```

The `fname` variable was assigned the *literal* text `assets/*.drx`. When you used it *unquoted* in the `echo`, the shell dutifully expanded it.